# Functional programming — for and while loops

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm trying to write `for` and `while` loops in Python — functional programming style.

I think `for` construct is fine, but `while` doesn't work, it runs infinitely.

```
# for loop
lst = [1, 2, 3]
def fun(e):
   return e
print map(fun, lst)


# while loop
i = 1
def whileloop():
    global i
    print i
    i = i+1
while_FP = lambda: ((i < 5) and whileloop()) or while_FP()
while_FP()
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the point of this exercise?

Comment: Who needs a point to this sort of thing?  He's learning and experimenting, which is awesome.

Comment: I think you need `lambda i=i: ...`. Currently it only checks whether `i<5` when you initialize the lambda.

Comment: @SomeKittens That's why he said out of curiosity

Comment: Um... For loops and while loops are by definition not functional programming style. They both repeatedly execute statements, which is only useful if those statements cause side effects visible outside the loop. The essence of functional style is to avoid computations that use side effects to communicate their results.

Comment: How is this "functional programming style"? Because of recursion?? You're still incrementing mutable variables in a loop. An FP approach would be based on induction over the structure of your sequence...

Comment: @John, FP-style don't uses loops :) It uses map/filter/reduce :) And never uses global variables!!!

Comment: I was going through, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-prog/index.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FP-style don't uses global state (global variables) and minimizes the side effects (IO for ex.). While-loop shout look like this:

```
fp_while = lambda pred, fun, acc: (lambda val: fp_while(pred, fun, val) if pred(val) else val)(fun(acc))

print fp_while(lambda x: x < 5, lambda x: x + 1, 1)
```

if you need a side effect:

```
def add_and_print(x):
   print x
   return x + 1

fp_while(lambda x: x < 5, add_and_print, 1)
```

Comment: It's complex in Python. It's simple in an FP language: `while p f x | p x = x | otherwise = while p f (f x)`

Answer (score 2):

Using recursion as in answer by @aleksei-astynax-pirogov will cause recursion error if you have too many iterations.
Instead you can hide the side effect of the state inside a function.

```py
def fp_while(pred, fun, acc):
    v = acc
    while(pred(v)):
        v = fun(v)
    return v
```

Usage example:

```py
fp_while(lambda x: x < 5, lambda x: x + 1, 1)
print(fp_while(lambda x: x < 5, lambda x: x + 1, 1))
# outputs 5
```

**Using generators approach**

The below generator approach will allow you to store the state at each iteration

```py
def fp_while_generator(pred, fun, acc):
    v = acc
    while(pred(v)):
        yield v
        v = fun(v)
    yield v # remove this if you do not want the last value that fails the check
```

Usage example:

```py
my_while_generator = fp_while_generator(lambda x: x < 5, lambda x: x + 1, 1)
print([i for i in my_while_generator])
# outputs [1,2,3,4,5]
```

More info on generators
https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/

Answer (score -1):

probably you need:

```
i = 1
def whileloop():
    global i
    print i
    i = i+1
    return True

while_FP = lambda: ((i < 5) and whileloop()) and while_FP()
while_FP()
```

from a functional point of view `and` evaluates the right field if the left one is `True`. You can rewrite it using `or` also. By the way it is not a good pratice to use globals.