# How to Loop x Times With Functional Style?

Tags: python, functional-programming, iteration

I have this recursive function:

```
def lifecycle(population):
    ...
    lifecycle(new_population)
```

I want to perform this loop 100 times. I want to use correct functional style. So, I cannot use a counter? Because assigning new values to a variable is not okay in functional programming. How does one do this functionally? I'm using Python.

Comment: You can't do this without this without a counter variable.

Comment: [Pythonic way to loop n times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970780/pythonic-way-to-do-something-n-times)

Comment: [Functional Programming - for and while loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981037/functional-programming-for-and-while-loops)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, like this:

```
def lifecycle(population, i):
    if i == 100:
        return ...
    ...
    return lifecycle(new_population, i + 1)
```

But this is a really, really silly thing to do in Python (and it fails for all but the smallest examples, due to tail calls being not optimized). Just use a loop, although that uses mutable state under the hood, the remaining program can be perfectly functional.

Answer (score 2):

You do it recursively, and by adding a decreasing (or increasing) loop variable.

```
def lifecycle(population, n):
    if n == 0:
        return population
    ...
    return lifecycle(new_population, n-1)
```

You must return the population if you want it to be truly functional because functional programming frowns upon side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this for example:

```
def lifecycle(population, n, maxN):
    if n >= maxN: return
    new_population = population
    lifecycle(new_population, n+1, maxN)

lifecycle(['an initial population or something'], 0, 1000)
```